# SQL How to populate a NULL value

Tags: sql

Here is my scenario:

I have a table with fields:

```
PolicyID
MemberType 
MemberAddress
MemberCity
```

There are 2 `MemberType` classifications:

```
MemberType
----------
Owners  
Dependents
```

Only the `Owners` are linked to an address and a city. So when I have an owner and several family members (Dependents) only the owners row shows an address, the dependents row address field shows `NULL` (Side note: an owner and dependent of the same family will have the same `policyid`). How can I populate the address field so when there is a dependent with a `NULL` address field it will grab the address of its owner and populate the field.

**Current Results**

```
PolicyID    MemberType  MemberAddress    MemberCity 
--------------------------------------------------
 1234       Owner       9785 sw 197 ct   Miami 
 1234       Dependent   NULL             NULL 
 1234       Spouse      NULL             NULL
```

**Desired Results**

```
PolicyID    MemberType  MemberAddress     MemberCity
---------------------------------------------------- 
1234        Owner       9785 sw 197 ct    Miami 
1234        Dependent   9785 sw 197 ct    Miami 
1234        Spouse      9785 sw 197 ct    Miami
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look into `IsNull` or `Coalesce`

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Also tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: You could do that with an update statement but to help your with that we'd need your exact table structure

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t
SET t.MemberAddress = t2.MemberAddress and t.MemberCity=t2.MemberCity
FROM Table1 t 
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t.Id = t2.Id 
WHERE t2.PolicyID = t.PolicyID AND t.MemberType<>'Owner' AND t.MemberAddress IS NULL
```

before running the update check to ensure you are updating correct data:

```
SELECT t.PolicyID, t2.PolicyID, t.MemberType, t2.MemberType, t.MemberAddress, t2.MemberAddress, t.MemberCity, t2.MemberCity
FROM Table1 t 
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t.Id = t2.Id 
WHERE t2.PolicyID = t.PolicyID AND t.MemberType='Dependents' AND t.MemberAddress IS NULL
```

Comment: Current Results   
PolicyID MemberType MemberAddress MemberCity
1234 Owner         9785 sw 197 ct          Miami
1234 Dependant         NULL                  NULL
1234 Spouse                 NULL                  NULL
   
Desired Results   
PolicyID MemberType MemberAddress MemberCity
1234 Owner          9785 sw 197 ct Miami
1234 Dependant  9785 sw 197 ct Miami
1234 Spouse          9785 sw 197 ct Miami

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a simple join in your `update` statement like this:

```
UPDATE p1
  SET p1.MemberAddress = p2.MemberAddress,
      p1.MemberCity = p2.MemberCity
FROM policy p1
INNER JOIN policy p2 ON p1.PolicyID = p2.PolicyID
    AND p2.MemberType = 'Owner'
WHERE p1.MemberType <> 'Owner';

select * from policy;  --change it to match your tablename
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2388/4/1)